# RHEL 6 update to 7 issue when reboot

Tags: linux, rhel

I have upgrade RHEL 6 to 7 on Redhat-upgrade-tool and use command "preupg" Check fail before run update to RHEL 7. The preupg result show this fail **" |Requirements for the /usr/ Directory                 fail| "** I have already fixed. And run command "preupg" agian for check fail from result and update to RHEL 7

In last process must reboot for change to rhel 7
Btw OS boot i found stuck in service and boot loop
Please recommend way to fix this

Thanks.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RHEL 6 -> 7 upgrade tool will not work if `/usr` is a separate mount point, and that is why `preupg` checks for that.

You said you fixed that. But since the system is still looking for `dev-mapper-vg_os\x2dlv_usr.device` (= a systemd `.device` unit file for /dev/mapper/vg_os-lv_usr`, also known as` /dev/vg_os/lv_usr`), then you must have missed something.

- Did you **completely remove** the `/etc/fstab` line that tells the system to mount `/dev/mapper/vg_os-lv_usr` to `/usr`? It must be completely removed (not just commented out), or else the upgrade will fail.
- In `/etc/default/grub`, there might be a boot option telling the initramfs that the `vg_os/lv_usr` logical volume is needed. That should have been removed also, once the `/usr` was merged into the root filesystem. In RHEL6 style the boot option would have been `rd_LVM_LV=vg_os/lv_usr`, in RHEL7 style options it will be `rd.lvm.lv=vg_os/lv_usr`.

If you missed the latter step, you should interrupt GRUB (by pressing e.g. up/down arrow keys when the GRUB menu appears), then highlight the new RHEL7 kernel and press <kbd>E</kbd> to edit the boot option. Then find the line that starts with either `linux` or `linuxefi`, look for `rd.lvm.lv=vg_os/lv_usr` boot option on that line, and delete it. (The `linux`/`linuxefi` line can be very long, and so it can be wrapped to several lines.) Once the obsolete boot option is removed, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to boot with the edited boot options.

If your system now boots successfully, remember to edit `/etc/default/grub` to persistently remove that boot option, and then use `grub2-mkconfig` to update the GRUB configuration for real:

- `grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg` for legacy BIOS systems, or
- `grub-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/EFI/redhat/grub.cfg` for UEFI systems.

Assuming you have a RedHat account, you might want to read [this RedHat support document](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/909603). Note the last line in the document.